# Why a type guard does not narrow a type?

Tags: typescript, typeguards, type-narrowing

I've got some code that is using a type guard function:

```
function assertInstanceOf<T>(
  value: any,
  expected_type: new(...args: any[]) => T,
): value is T {
  if (value instanceof expected_type) { return true; }

  notify(`value '${value}' was not expected type '${expected_type.name}'`);

  return false;
}
```

In the following scenario, the type guard doesn't seem to stick:

```
const save_sig_check = $modal.find('#save_signature')[0];
const is_html_input_element =
  save_sig_check && assertInstanceOf(save_sig_check, HTMLInputElement);

if (is_html_input_element && save_sig_check.checked) {
  this.saveSignatureData(name, output);
}
```

TypeScript reports:

```
error TS2339: Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

113     if (is_html_input_element && save_sig_check.checked) {
                                                    ~~~~~~~
```

However, if I rearrange the code like so, TypeScript does not complain:

```
if (!save_sig_check || !assertInstanceOf(save_sig_check, HTMLInputElement)) {
  return true;
}

if (save_sig_check.checked) {
  this.saveSignatureData(name, output);
}
```

This second is a little harder for me to read, so was wondering why the first doesn't work. Any ideas? Still using TypeScript 2.8.3.

Comment: I don't think type narrowing propagates across boolean variables.

Answer (score 0):

SLaks's comment is right: saving the result of a test in a variable and then branching on the variable does not perform narrowing.  Here's [the suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24865).